# Spring STS not able to see other framework file

Tags: java, spring, automation, frameworks

Iam following a guide on how to automate testing on Pluralsight. Iam using Java and Spring STS. The problem I have is, Spring cant find one of the files called Pages. Heres my explorer window so if gives you an idea on how it looks:

[Issue screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbjUT.jpg)

The UnitTest file basically cant find the Pages.java file. Ive updated my project files but it still cant find it.
Any ideas or suggestions on what the problem could be?

```
@Test
public void canGoToHomePage() {
    Pages.homePage().goTo();
    Assert.assertTrue(Pages.homePage().isAt());
}
```

Comment: From screenshots, it seems there are 2 different projects. If it is a different project, you need to add the 1st project as dependency.

Comment: Thanks Yogi. I looked in the POM file and it turns it was missing a small line of code to one of the package files. Its now seeing the Pages file now. Thanks again for your input.